# How do I use a NSFetchRequest with an NSExpression and .dictionaryResultType as a SwiftUI @FetchRequest?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a model with two entities: Category and Transaction (simplified)

```
Category
--------
title: String
transactions: Transaction[]

Transaction
-----------
title: String
amount: Double
date: Date
category: Category
```

They are one-to-many so one category can hold multiple transactions. I am trying to sum  up the total value of all Transactions within a category and within a given date frame. For example, I would like to know all transactions from march 2022 in the category "Food". I have come up with this (currently only fetching from the past 30 days)

```
  let sumExpression = NSExpressionDescription()
  let keypathAmount = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "amount")
  sumExpression.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [keypathAmount])
  sumExpression.name = "sum"
  sumExpression.expressionResultType = .doubleAttributeType
  
  let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Transaction")
  let adjustedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -30, to: Date()) ?? Date()
  let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", adjustedDate as CVarArg)
  request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(
    type: .and,
    subpredicates: [datePredicate, NSPredicate(format: "category == %@", category)]
  )
  request.propertiesToFetch = [sumExpression]
  request.includesPendingChanges = false 
  request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
  request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
  request.returnsDistinctResults = true

  do {
    let results = try moc.fetch(request)
    let resultMap = results[0] as! [String:Double]
    return resultMap["sum"] ?? 0.0
  } catch let error as NSError {
    NSLog("Error when summing amounts: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
```

Since I use the `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc` I can't use the fetch request in the init() since the environment is not available yet. So right now I'm doing all this in the `onAppear()` of the view body. In said view, I have an `@ObservedObject` of the currently selected `Category`. This of course does not update when the transactions change (for example when a new one gets added). I can not use a `@FetchRequest` and initialize it with the above `NSFetchRequest` because Xcode throws

> 'NSFetchedResultsController does not support both change tracking and fetch request's with NSDictionaryResultType'

How do I circumvent this? What is the best way to fetch the sum of a filtered relationships attribute in SwiftUI? How do I leverage the existence of the `@ObservedObject category` to retry the fetch request when a change is occurring?

Comment: Derived Properties likely offer a better approach.

Comment: Is it possible to use derived properties with a filtered fetch request though? If I understand it correctly they would allow me to keep the sum of `category.transactions` in the db, but that would be ALL transactions and not just the ones filtered by date range. Thats where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with a Singleton that gets initialized in the app root and injected into each view that needs it as a @StateObject. The Singleton gets access to the `NSManagedObjectContext` via a one-time setup method. It uses the `NotificationCenter` via `NSManagedObjectContext.didSaveObjectsNotification` to listen to model changes and recalculate. While a Singleton isn't really popular to use in SwiftUI (often for good reason!) this one does not affect the underlying data, it just enriches and presents it.